# Angular Micro Front-End

Tags: angular, micro-frontend

I have been doing some research in regards to micro front-ends, and I am sold on the concept of developing a applet/feature/module once and implementing it across other applications that might need that feature.
However I do wonder, lets say I build a google maps component and I use it across 3 other applications, if I edit/update that code on the main component, does that mean I will have to log into each application, do a git pull and redeploy the app? I know IFrames can sort this out, but it kind off feels a little bit like a hack.
Also there is no support for a PWA micro front-end and angular does allow pwa support but not native elements like ionic.

Answer (score 0):

u can generate js bundle and deploy it on some server and 3 other application will download it every time or like u said - some npm package with versions and up version every time then u update this package